# Separar en columnas por valores únicos en R

Tags: r, dataframe

dispongo de un data frame  (contsMg) que tiene los siguientes campos:

| Mg g/kg | categoria | cod | y | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | bosque | 1 | 14.62 | 90.1 |
| 50 | pastura | 2 | 15.58 | 90.05 |
| 80 | pastura | 2 | 14.81 | 90.25 |
| 35 | urbano | 3 | 15.75 | 90.23 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

este tiene otros 25,000 objetos distribuidos en 50 categorías con su código y contenidos de magnesio,  este dataframe viene de un spatialpixeldataframe que he coercionado al agregar los cod y nombre de categorias para cada pixel, la referencia geográfica no me interesa de momento.

los que necesito es agrupar todos los valores de magnesio en un nuevo objeto según su categoría en columnas para analizar y compararlos, de la siguente manera asi:

| bosque | pastura | urbano | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 80 | 10 | ... |
| 50 | 30 | 15 | ... |
| 80 | 25 | 22 | ... |
| 35 | 15 | 11 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

tengo entendido que puede realizarse mediante un ciclo y valores únicos en una lista, gracias por su ayuda.

la lista la he creado así:

```
lis <-list(unique(contsmg$categoria))
```

y el objeto donde pienso ir agregandolos

```
mg_uso <- data.frame()
```

pero el bucle o lo que sea necesario no tengo idea de como realizarlo

```
for (i in 1:length(lis)) {...
```

Comment: Bienvenido alan350, nos alegra que te sumes a stackoverflow. Para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas te sugiero revisar esta pagina donde muestran [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). También puedes realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que aprendas un poco más de como funciona la pagina y de paso ganar tur primeras medallas. En este caso particular seria bueno que agregaras tus datos como texto no como imágenes.

Comment: Alan no importa el orden en el que se coloquen los valores de magnesio?

Comment: no importa el orden de las columnas media vez todos los elementos que contengan correspondan a la categoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente código utiliza dplyr y tidyr   para lograr lo que necesitas. Los datos quedan ordenados como aparecen en tu `df` original.

```
#Cargamos librerías necesarias

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#Leemos los datos
df <- read.table( text ="
    'Mg g/kg' categoria cod 
    40 bosque 1 
    50 pastura 2
    80 pastura 2
    35 urbano 3
    ", header =T)

# Simulamos datos faltantes y corregimos nombres
df$y <- rnorm(4,15)
df$x <- rnorm(4,90)
names(df)[1]<-'Mg g/kg'

df

#Pasamos a formato ancho la data usando pivot_wider
#Antes es necesario crear un id para ordenar los datos 
#por categoria (grup_by y mutate)
#con select tomamos solo las variables que ocupa pivot_wider
#Por ultimo eliminamos el id.
#Si el número de datos que tiene cada categoría es distinto al 
#final de las categorías con un menor numero de datos se llenara con NA.
df%>%
    group_by(categoria)%>%
    mutate(id = 1:n())%>%
    select(id,categoria,'Mg g/kg')%>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = categoria, values_from = 'Mg g/kg')%>%
    select(-id)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias rolando, ha funcionado a la perfeccion

Comment: Hola @RolandoTamayo  el dia de ayer no tuve mayor dificultad para realizarlo, pero al volver a reporoducir tengo el siguiente error: `Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'select': unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"grouped_df"’` ,  a que se debe esto?

Comment: ....bueno ya lo he encontrado, parece que sucede cuando tengo cargados los paquetes raster y stars, pero sigo con la duda si puede resolverse sin necesidad de quitarlos

Comment: Es un conflicto entre los paquetes, pues todos tienen la función `select` y cada uno la define a su manera. Usa `dplyr::select` para espesificar que quieres usar la función en esta libreria. Así podras ocupar los otros paquetes, y si quieres ocupar el `select` de `raster` o `stars` tendiras que llamarlos de manera similar  `raster::select` y `stars::select`